# How random_state works in lightGBM algorithm?

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm

Why is not it a unique process?
Specifically, which part has randomness?

I only know random forest.
random forest uses bootstrap data, so I can understand its randomness.

Answer (score 0):

Same in GBM - random-number generator is used in feature and example sampling. That's used to reduce overfitting